# Game views: instance variables vs. singletons?

Tags: architecture

If I have views that I will re-use when they are displayed, which would be a better approach: creating instance variables of them in the class that handles showing the views, or defining the views as singletons and then referencing them for their own class?

So this...

```
class Game
{
    GameView view = new GameView();

    void Method() 
    {
        view.Show();
    }
}
```

...or this?

```
void Method()
{
    GameView.Instance.Show();
}
```

Is this just a matter of preference? The Game will be a singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless these views are expensive to create, make them new instances.  It eases testing, and allows for architectural patterns like IOC.

Plus, are you sure you will never need 2 to exist?

Answer (score 1):

The thing with singleton ... don't use them unless you have really good reasons to do so. Not having a better idea is not a good reason!

You see, when singletons were introduced by the GoF, they were meant as *solution* to problems that need some sort of *global state*. But too many people got it the wrong way - "you see, now that there is a pattern for it, it is fine to go for global state". And that is simply wrong.

*Global state* makes your application harder to test and maintain; it adds coupling between different parts of your code that normally should have anything to do with each other.

So, long story short: go for instance variables. But maybe, instead of creating your GameView objects directly, look into [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) so that your Game objects receive their Views from some framework, instead of having such tight coupling as in your example.